# What do you call the act of searching a list of words related to another word?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the act of searching a list of words (not just synonyms) related to another word?

For example searching every word related to medicine, which includes all illnesses, equipment, professions, all biological terms used and more.

I think for this one there are several words. I don't mind if the word implies more than just finding and listing them (mapping and categorizing could be implied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call that "research". One might add a modifier, such as "lexicographical research". I don't know of a specific term meaning just compiling and looking through a list of terms related to some subject.